# Moving SALT from a paper wallet

Tags: wallets

I have some SALT tokens held on an EthAddress.org paper wallet. I want to move them to my Exodus wallet but when I type the private key in (I have triple checked that I enter it correctly) it gives an error message saying there are not enough funds? I have checked my public address on Etherscan and it shows the tokens are there. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1):

Even if you have the tokens there, you need Ether to pay for the transfer. That's probably what the error message is saying.

So transfer a bit of Ether to your wallet to pay for the gas. Have a look at https://ethgasstation.info/ to estimate how much you need. Remember that you need some Ether also for the transfer from the exchange(?) to your wallet.

Comment: Ah! That makes sense I'll give it a try. Thanks Lauri.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work. I still get the same error message even though I now have 0.073 ETH in my Exodus wallet? It recognises the address OK as it shows me the correct public address? Any ideas please?

Comment: Never used ethaddress.org paper wallet so a difficult to say. But any wallet should show you what assets you have there - does the wallet show the tokens when you enter the private key? (If no, you're probably using a wrong private key and not the one linked to the public address)